# Detect and find centres for tiny black rings using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection, matlab-cvst

I have tried finding answers to search how to detect very tiny rings in an image with white background. But every where they have solutions for the detection of black dots.
Please help me with how to proceed. I have just started using matlab and still learning the basics of the tool.
The image which in which I wanna detect the rings is as below!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If speed is not your main goal and you have the Computer Vision Toolbox, I would usggest using the MSER algorithm like this:

```
Image=imread('YourRings.bmp'); 
Image=rgb2gray(Image);

 Regions=detectMSERFeatures(Image);
 plot(Regions);
```

Result:[image]

If you study and understand the methods and caracteristics of the class, you can also filter unwanted results (bigger or eccentric ellipses) without morphological operators.

Comment: Thank you all, Mr.McMa I dont have Computer Vision Toolkit installed in my matlab as I am using R2012a version. Is their any other process in which i can get the exact stuff what you have suggested.

Comment: I use MEX files of OpenCV functions (See [1], also some bindings in the OpenCV 3.0 Alpha) which work as good or even better. If you plan to do further image processing and computer vision I would strongly recomend to install them, but if this one is your only task, maybe that's kind of an overkill.

  [1]: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/3225-mexopencv-collection-and-a-develo

Answer (score 0):

one simple option is:

1. do a edge detection (laplacian, canny ect), the width of the filter must be smaller the ring width, to recognize both ring edges.
2. then search for circles.
3. for each circle search an additional (only one) circle inside of it.
4. when found circle inside of circle mark as a ring (you have the inner and outer limits marked by the edges).

Answer (score 0):

If the rings are closed you can [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) (using 4-connect) the entire image. The largest region will belong to the background and can be ignored. Then you can use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to find the centroid of the rest of the rings.

```
 lb = bwlabel( inputBW, 4 );
 st = regionprops( lb, 'Centroid', 'Area' );
 [bgArea toRemove] = max( [st(:).Area] );
 st(toRemove) = []; %// discard background
 cnt = vertcat( st.Centroid ); %// all centers
```

Displaying the results as grenn 'X's at the center of the rings.

```
 figure;   
 imshow( inputBW ); hold on;
 scatter( cnt(:,1), cnt(:,2), 50, 'xg' );
```

If the rings are not closed, you can use some morphological operations ([`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html)) as a pre-processing to close them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I am getting a blank array "cnt" and hence exception in scatter(). Please provide suggestions.

Comment: @AmarBanerjee it is difficult to debug without looking at a real input image. But it seems like your rings are not close and thus you have a single region covering both background and the interior of the rings. If you can upload an example input image and the result of `bwlabel` on that image - it would help a lot.